# Hibernate + MySQL (Eclipse, Maven) помогите корректно сконфигурировать

Tags: mysql, eclipse, hibernate

### Вот структура проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**POM.XML**

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>maven-jar-hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-hibernate</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>by.edu.java.buglak</name>
  <description>maven jar hibernate test project</description>
  <build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <configuration>
   <archive>
    <manifest>
     <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
    </manifest>
   </archive>
  </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.9</version>
  </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
     <version>5.2.5.Final</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
     <version>5.2.5.Final</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
     <version>5.3.4.Final</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>mysql</groupId>
     <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
     <version>5.1.40</version>
 </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**HIBERNATE.CFG.XML**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">12345</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**HibernateUtil.java**

```html
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {
 private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

 static {
  Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure();
  StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfg.getProperties());
  try {
   sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
  }
 }

 public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
  return sessionFactory;
 }
}
```

**Main.java**

```js
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
 }
}
```

**Console Eclipse**

```html
янв 06, 2017 11:03:23 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.5.Final}
янв 06, 2017 11:03:23 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
янв 06, 2017 11:03:23 PM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
янв 06, 2017 11:03:23 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
янв 06, 2017 11:03:23 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
янв 06, 2017 11:03:23 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate]
янв 06, 2017 11:03:23 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
янв 06, 2017 11:03:23 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
янв 06, 2017 11:03:23 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 10 (min=1)
янв 06, 2017 11:03:24 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
янв 06, 2017 11:03:24 PM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.3.4.Final
янв 06, 2017 11:03:24 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@5a7fe64f] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
```

> Если в hibernate.cfg.xml параметр hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create то в
>   Console  последние строчки буд иметь вид

```html
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 10 (min=1)
янв 06, 2017 11:10:47 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
янв 06, 2017 11:10:48 PM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.3.4.Final
янв 06, 2017 11:10:48 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl applyImportSources
INFO: HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@5276d6ee'
```

> Помогите пожалуйста! Что я делаю не так? Как мне добиться корректного
>   соединения Hibernate+MySQL из Eclipse? Заранее спасибо! ...
>
> **Вижу все подключается, что нужно поправить, вот этот лог что означает?** INFO: HHH10001501:
>   Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess
>   [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@5a7fe64f]
>   for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the
>   Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection
>   will be set into auto-commit mode.

Comment: пожалуйста, конкретизируйте вопрос. какие ошибки? какой результат вы ожидаете?

Comment: Ожидаю: PM org.hibernate.tools.hbm2dll.SchemaUpdate execute INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete